# How Do I Open a Pop Up Window over Destination URL?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I want to link to a url and after the destination page opens, pop up a window over it. I've seen some examples of this but don't know how to code it. I'm a .NET developer but perhaps this needs javascript? Anyone know how to do it?

Page 1

Link 2 Page 2 --->  Page 2 opens... Popup opens over Page 2.

Thanks.

Comment: can you give us a little of code like the popup template? Do you use bootstrap framework?

Comment: I know how to open a popup window with window.open() but I don't know how to open a destination url first and then a popup over it. I don't have any code because I don't know how to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach #1:

In Page 2:

```
<script>
if (document.referrer === "URL of Page 1 goes here")
{
    window.open("URL of popup goes here", "_blank");
}
</script>
```

Thus the popup will only appear if you arrived at Page 2 via a link from Page 1.

Approach #2 (if you cannot modify Page 2):

In Page 1:

```
<script>
    function page2popup()
    {
        window.open("URL of popup goes here", "_blank");
    }
</script>
<a href="URL of Page 2 goes here" onclick="page2popup();">Page 2</a>
```

Comment: This works except the window opened by the page2popup opens a new tab instead of a popup window over the destination page (which is page2).  How do I get it to pop up over the destination page?

Comment: OK I got it; replace the window.open with this:  newwindow=window.open(urltopop,'title','height=300,width=350', "_blank");
 if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
 return false;

I just have to add in the center to window code... 
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that there is no universally supported way to ensure that a popup comes up in a new window rather than a new tab (this is intentional - it is supposed to be determined by browser preferences set by the user).  There are various techniques, like the one you found, that work in particular browsers, but they are not defined by the HTML spec and are thus not guaranteed to work in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing this in html, then

> page1.html

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="page2.html">click to go to page to page2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

> page2.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function popup(){
        //alert("this is page 2");
        window.open("http://www.geekzgarage.com"); 
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="popup()">
    this is page 2 and popup window is opened as provided in the link given..
</body>
</html>
```