# Joomla - Pop up only appears automatically when from a specific page

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, popup, virtuemart

I have a question on which I cannot find an answer online.

I'm making a website where I want a pop up to appear only when the visitor comes from a certain page. So to be more specific:

When someone is directed to maakeencocktail.nl/Apple-Nojito from maakeencocktail.nl/cocktail-engine, they should be shown a pop up.

However, when people arrive on maakeencocktail.nl/Apple-Nojito from maakeencocktail.nl/cocktail-overview they should not see the pop up.

Is it possible to set these kind of conditions for pop ups?? I'm working with Joomla! 3.4.8, VirtueMart 3.0.12.

I have already tried these solutions, but they didn't work for me: [How Do I Open a Pop Up Window over Destination URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169827/how-do-i-open-a-pop-up-window-over-destination-url)

Hope one of you gentle guys can help me out with this. I'm at a loss!

Comment: try to include your popup script in a php codition by checking referer URL using $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]

Answer (score 0):

You should just check the referer in the popup module, and add a condition to display the popup only when the referer matches that of your choice.

We did develop a lightbox Joomla module - it's on our blog and can be downloaded for free. You can just modify it slightly to serve your needs.